# Why _block_load_blocks() does not work?

Tags: 7, blocks

[_block_load_blocks()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/_block_load_blocks/7) returns an empty array. `block_list($region)`, which uses `_block_load_blocks()` returns nothing as well. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be at least a block, as the "Main page content" block is always associated with a region. You always need to select a region for that block, as the "-None-" option is not available when selecting a region for it.

[image: Seven]

[image: Bartik]

The list of blocks can be altered from modules. If a module is removing the "Main page content" block from the list, it doesn't appear in the list, and the list would be empty, if there aren't any other enabled blocks. `_block_load_blocks()` contains the following code.

```
$block_info = $result->fetchAllAssoc('bid');
// Allow modules to modify the block list.
drupal_alter('block_list', $block_info);
```